# Comparing flowering duration for Cherries, Cherry Blossom, Other Stone Fruit, Apples

Tags: fruit-trees, flowering, cherries

Are there any rules of thumb for how long various fruit trees flower for?

Of specific interest - do Cherry Blossom trees have blossoms for significantly longer then regular cherry trees ?   Similarly, are there any fruit trees known for their blossoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various species and varieties have different typical flowering durations, but there's generally a good amount of similarity. Some cherry trees, eg some mature older variety sweet dark cherries, may sometimes flower quite intensively for over a week, some branches on the same tree flowering predominantly several days apart. And for the same tree, production can vary greatly from year to year, even with similar moisture & temperature conditions etc. Some apple varieties flower for over two weeks, cf many cherries which  tend to flower most intensively for a week or so.

Cherry Blossom Trees/ Sakura, *Prunus serrulata*, when looking at the specific exact same trees in different years, tend to flower profusely for about five or six days, most intensively for about two or three: a lot depends on whether there is rain or not, & how much, & how much wind; there are generally a few flowers for about two weeks. There are variations from year to year, sometimes profuse Sakura for four or so days! After about three days new leaves tend to begin to become more noticeable along with the blossoms.

Adjacent trees in parks/ orchards etc tend to flower fairly consistently, in part because the conditions are fairly identical. Also, trees of the same variety in the same region tend to flower at about the same time.

In addition to Sakura viewing, there are places that have Apple Blossom Festivals, and some places have Cherry Festivals etc, though the festivals generally have to do with several kinds of apple & cherry varieties.